# PHP Regexp - Remove redundant spaces but keep line breaks

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that removes redundant (two or more) spaces but keeps line breaks.

Any idea how that would work?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove spaces and tabs

```
preg_replace("/[ \t]+/", " ", $myval);
```

Remove only spaces

```
preg_replace("/[ ]+/", " ", $myval);
```

Comment: This reg remove ALL spaces or tabs.

Comment: The first question asked for removal of ALL spaces. Have adjusted the regex so it will remove only redundant spaces and replace it with one space.

Answer (score 3):

Removes 2 ore more spaces:

```
preg_replace("/[ ]{2,}/", " ", $myval);
```

Comment: You probably want to replace them with a single space, unless you're going to remove all spaces as long there are more than one.

Answer (score 2):

This will replace all "spaces" but newline by a space

```
$str = "a   bc


d e       f";
$str = preg_replace('/[^\S\n]+/', ' ', $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
a bc


d e f
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace all horizontal whitespace symbols with a single space in a string, you can use

```
preg_replace('/\h+/', ' ', $str);
```

where `\h` is a PCRE-specific shorthand character class matching [all characters that `\p{Zs}` matches](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm) plus `U+0009` (a horizontal tab).

The quantifier `+` after `\h` enables matching one or more horizontal whitespace symbols. To only match two or more occurrences, use a limiting quantifier:

```
preg_replace('/\h{2,}/', ' ', $str);
```